# Azure Devops send closed work items to slack

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am having a release pipeline in Azure Devops which will send my generated .msi file to a slack channel. This is a good way to give a running testable installation to my testers. The problem here is, that they don't know which User Stories are resolved and which they need to test. So is there a way to also send the closed User Stories / Tasks since the last Pull Request?

Comment: Hi Did you check out below workarounds, how did it go?

Comment: Hi, I haven't got the time to try one of the provided solutions, but i will do as soon as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to send the closed User Stories/Task to the testers.

For example you can create a query to get all the closed workitems. Query supports to email the query results. Please check the [tutorial to create a query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/using-queries?view=azure-devops#create-a-query).

[image]

You can also send the query from the pipeline using [Scheduled Work Item Query extenstion](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Quadrotech.ADOScheduledWorkItemQuery&targetId=47097972-e633-4284-ad72-fe49f3c8dd5f). Install this extension and then add `Scheduled Work Item Query` task in your pipeline.

If you want to retrieve the closed workitems by adding a script task in the pipeline to call rest api. You can refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60398674/days-between-dates-in-azure-devops-work-items-by-query/60408505#60408505).

You can also check out integration [Azure Boards with Slack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/integrations/boards-slack?view=azure-devops) or [Azure devops with Slack](https://zapier.com/apps/azure-devops/integrations/slack), which will send notifications for update workitem events in to Slack channel.