# How to restore WorkItem states after losing states by moving them to a different project

Tags: azure-devops

With Azure DevOps Service, we split our main project and moved ~1500 WorkItems/PBIs/Features/... to a new Project.

We wrote a Boards->Queries, selected all and moved them to the new Project.

By doing this, all States of the WorkItems were reset (ActivatedBy, ActivatedDate, State, Board Column).
We can see the old states by looking into the Revision Tab.

Is there a way or a tool to restore or undo the changes made by that move?

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to check out below workaround. How did it go?

Comment: Hi @LeviLu-MSFT . We are not using the tool you suggested. We are currently writing a simple api tool on the basis of danielorns approach.
Thank you for your large answer. I am very certain, that this will be usefull to the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When [moving the work item to a new project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/move-change-type?view=azure-devops#move-a-work-item-to-another-project) a new revision of the workitem is created.

Moving between projects is further complicated by that there is no guarantee for the same process being used, meaning that even if you move to the same type [fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process-field?view=azure-devops) may be missing/added or have other [rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/custom-rules?view=azure-devops) applied to them. Thus Azure DevOps automatically resets the State and Reason fields to the default initial values for the work item type that you move.

What you need to do is to go through all workitems that were moved and restore the fields to the value of the previous revision. This can of coruse be done by hand, but with 1500 workitems automating it through the Rest API (or Azure CLI) is probably your better option:

1. Get a list of Id's that were moved by doing a [wiql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/wiql-syntax?toc=%2Fvsts%2Fwork%2Ftrack%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fvsts%2Fwork%2Ftrack%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops-rest-6.0) search that selects all those workitems.([Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query%20by%20wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0), [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/boards?view=azure-cli-latest#ext_azure_devops_az_boards_query))
2. Get the revision just before the workitem was moved. Pay special attention to the `asOf`/`--as-of` parameter that allows you to retrieve a work item revision from a given date. Set this to just before you made the move from the original project. ([Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20item?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#get-work-item-with-asof-parameter), [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/boards/work-item?view=azure-cli-latest#ext_azure_devops_az_boards_work_item_show))
3. Update the relevant fields with the previous value (this will create a new revision on the workitem and effctively "restore" your lost fields ([Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#update-a-field), [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/boards/work-item?view=azure-cli-latest#ext_azure_devops_az_boards_work_item_update))

Using the Azure CLI is probably a bit more straightforward, but the REST API offers functionality like [retrieving workitems in batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20items%20batch?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) and to [update workitems in batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/workitembatchupdate?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to optimize the process, but for just 1500 items that should hardly matter.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to restore the changed fields.

If you plan to use rest api to restore the changed fields. You can use below rest apis.

1, You can use [Wiql - Query By Wiql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query%20by%20wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) rest api to get all your work items as danielorn mentioned. See [this thread for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60398674/days-between-dates-in-azure-devops-work-items-by-query/60408505#60408505) how to write scripts to call wiql rest api.

2, After you get all the work items. You can get their current revsion by the `rev` field. Then you can use [Revisions - Get rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/revisions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to get their original fields values at the previous version by current `rev - 1`.

3, Then yo can use [update rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#update-a-field) to restore the work item.

However, there is a simpler solution by using [Azure DevOps Migration Tools](https://nkdagility.github.io/azure-devops-migration-tools/) to migrate your workitems.

First you can delete all the work items that moved from the main project to the new Project.

Then you can use Azure DevOps Migration Tools to re-migrate the work items. Please check out the document carefully to learn how to use this tool. See below example:

1, Create a custom Migration tracking field

Before using the migration tool. You need create a custom Migration tracking field for the workitem type in the new project. This field will be used to track the origin work item in the Main project. See [here to add a custom field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/add-custom-field?view=azure-devops) in your project process.

Then you can set the customized tracking field(ie. `ReflectedWorkItemId2` ) in the configraton.json like below:

[image]

After the migration is done. You will see the origin workitem url is set in the custom field:

[image]

2, Map the fields and values(eg. area path, iteration path) in the FieldMaps section. See below example.

```
    {
      "$type": "MultiValueConditionalMapConfig",
      "WorkItemTypeName": "*",
      "sourceFieldsAndValues": {
        "System.AreaPath": "MainProject\\Development Team"
       
      },
      "targetFieldsAndValues": {
        "System.AreaPath": "NewProject"
        
      }
    },
    
    {
      "$type": "FieldValueMapConfig",
      "WorkItemTypeName": "*",
      "sourceField": "System.IterationPath",
      "targetField": "System.IterationPath",
      "defaultValue": "TestProjectAccess",
      "valueMapping": {
        "MainProject\\iteration 3": "NewProject\\Iteration 3",
        "MainProject\\iteration 5": "NewProject\\Iteration 2"
      }
    }
```

3, Map the states

```
{
      "$type": "FieldValueMapConfig",
      "WorkItemTypeName": "*",
      "sourceField": "System.State",
      "targetField": "System.State",
      "defaultValue": "New",
      "valueMapping": {
        "Approved": "New",
        "New": "New",
        "Developing": "Active",
        "To Do": "New",
        "Done": "Closed",
        "Removed": "Removed"
      }
    },
```

4, You can `WIQLQueryBit` field in the `WorkItemMigrationConfig` processor to only migrate the work items you want.

```
"Processors": [
    {
      "$type": "WorkItemMigrationConfig",
      "Enabled": true,
      ....
      "AppendMigrationToolSignatureFooter": false,
      "WIQLQueryBit": "AND [System.Id] IN (5,9)",
      "WIQLOrderBit": "[System.ChangedDate] desc",
      ...
     }
  ]
```