# Azure Devops Dashboard Functions using work item fields

Tags: azure-devops, dashboard

I have custome fields that use dates as a data type for my work items in Azure Devops Project? I would like to on a dashboard calculate the difference in number of days between two fields? Anyone have a step by step to accomplish this?

I have created a query to capture all the work items that are relevant and set the column options to include the fields needed for the equation but dont know how to add a widget that will perform the function on these fields and display the number of days between the two fields on my dashboard. (Audit finish date - Audit Start Date)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there's no such built-in feature can calculate the difference in number of days between two fields in dashboard or query.
But you could refer to the workaround in this ticket: [Days between dates in Azure DevOps work items by query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60398674/days-between-dates-in-azure-devops-work-items-by-query?rq=1) to see if it could somehow meet your requirement.